# php fgetcsv can not get scientific notation value as it show in formula area

Tags: php

I hava a csv file with data like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSdJe.png)

My code to read this csv file is:

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
            echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

It outputs：

```
1 fields in line 1:

1.19617E+11
1 fields in line 2:

1.13953E+11
1 fields in line 3:

1.19501E+11
```

But what I expect is actual value in csv（value display in formula area）：

119616896266

113953402648

119501389455

Can anyone help to solve this? Thank you!
(I came across this problem when I using phpspreadsheet, and I found it use fgetcsv to read file.)

Comment: The problem is with excel. If you'd open your csv in notepad, the csv is exactly what u need it to be. If u want to see the right value in excel, change the cell properties

Comment: @Naruto https://github.com/PHPOffice/PHPExcel/issues/1117 this issue says it can config to get the real value, but I tried and not work.

Comment: Try `$real = (float) $data[$c]` and `echo $real . "<br />\n"`, i.e. try casting it to float.

Comment: @HubQin you are making a CSV, not a PHPExcel document. I think you are mixing up things..

Comment: @Naruto Thank you! I try to convert csv to xls, and phpsreadsheet can get actual value now.